# Ember.js correct syntax for consecutive computed properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the following code in my controller. It first filters a set of results based on a search property, and then orders the results.

```js
results: function() {

    var searchTerm = this.get('searchTerm'),
        results = this.get('content');

    if (searchTerm) {
      results = results.filter(function(item) {
        return item.get('name').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
    }

  }.property('content', 'searchTerm', ),

sortedResults: Ember.computed.sort('results', 'sortProperties'),
    
sortProperties: function() {
    var order = this.get('ordering');
    if (order === 0) {
      return ['name:asc'];
    } else if (order === 1) {
      return ['name:desc'];
    }
  }.property('ordering'),
```

The template loops over sortedResults:

```html
{{#each sortedResults as |job|}}
    {{job-table-row model=job}} 
{{/each}}
```

The above works fine. I would like to finally subject sortedResults to a slice function to show a limited number of results. I have tried the following:

```js
slicedResults: function() {
    var sortedResults    = this.get('sortedResults');
    return sortedResults.slice(0,10);
}.property('sortedResults'),
```

Then looping over slicedResults:

```html
{{#each slicedResults as |job|}}
    {{job-table-row model=job}} 
{{/each}}
```

In this case, no results are returned. What would be the correct way to use the sorted results in a slice function and then output the result to the template?

Comment: Can you do `console.log(this.get('sortedResults'))` in your `slicedResults` property to make sure there is indeed something in `sortedResults` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to also observe the length of the sortedResults Array

```
slicedResults: function() {
    var sortedResults    = this.get('sortedResults');
    return sortedResults.slice(0,10);
}.property('sortedResults', 'sortedResults.length', 'sortedResults.@each')
```

Comment: Thank you- observing the length of the array was the important thing. What exactly is the purpose of 'sortedResults.@each'? I've tested without that, and everything still seems to work fine.

Comment: `@each` is used when you want to observe change on properties that are nested in your object. For example, you could want to observe on `sortedResults.@each.title`. *IMPORTANT NOTE*: `@each` only supports one level of nesting. For example, you cannot do `sortedResults.@each.someArray.@each.value`. Please see this for reference: https://gist.github.com/meelash/5785328 I do not know if the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

A more performant way we be to use the `array.[]` computed property.

```
slicedResults: function() {
    var sortedResults    = this.get('sortedResults');
    return sortedResults.slice(0,10);
}.property('sortedResults.[]')
```

This is a really helpful [blog post](https://blog.eladshahar.com/performant-array-computed-properties.html?utm_source=Ember+Weekly&utm_campaign=021238fa22-Ember_Weekly_Issue_121&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_e96229d21d-021238fa22-106355381) about the differences between the array computed properties.